# Is it possible to validate a select field with regex?

Tags: html, regex

I have been able to verify all other fields using regex, but the select field doesn't seem to be affected by a regex. The field is used to select a bank. here is the code:

```
<select class="fscf-input-select" id="fscf_field3_18" name="Bank[]">
    <option value="1">--not selected--</option>
    <option value="2">ABSA</option>
    <option value="3">Capitec</option>
    <option value="4">First National Bank</option>
    <option value="5">NedBank</option>
    <option value="6">Standard Bank</option>
</select>
```

The default is option 1, which is the text "--not selected--". Some users forget to select a bank, which causes the default text to be submitted. I have tried a regex such as

`/ABSA|Capitec|First National Bank|NedBank|Standard Bank/`

but there is not effect.

Is there maybe some way to validate this field using regex?

If regex can not be used, is there a way to ensure the user actually selects one of the options?

Comment: `the default text to be submitted` Hm, only value should be submitted, isn't it? Set `value=""` for it and add `required` validation.

Comment: In this case you have to check `value`. So this would work: `/2|3|4|5|6/`. Or in short: `/[2-6]{1}/`

Comment: why do you need regex for this? you know the value that is selected